# Can't assign characters to string variables

Tags: c++, string, variable-assignment, user-input

I'm trying to break up a user input string into different variables. The exact format of the user string must be "Tuesday 6:40 PM". I written the program so that once the loop hits the first space the rest of the variables will be filled because only the days name will be different lengths. I've tried this a few times and can't seem to get any sort of output.Anyone know why?

```
void input( Time & time ){
    string inputTime;
    string charholder;
    string day;
    string hour;
    string minute;
    string amPm;

    cout << "Enter a day and time: ";
    getline(cin, inputTime);

    for (int i = 0; i < inputTime.length() ; i++) {

        charholder = inputTime[i];
        cout << i << endl;

        if (charholder != " ") {
            day[i] = inputTime[i];
        }

        else {
            hour[0] = inputTime[i+1];
            minute[0] = inputTime[i+3];
            minute[1] = inputTime[i+4];
            amPm[0] = inputTime[i+6];
            amPm[1] = inputTime[i+7];
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << day << hour << minute << amPm; 
}
```

EDIT: CORRECT CODE:

```
void input( Time & time ){
    string inputTime;
    char charholder;
    string day;
    string hour;
    string minute;
    string amPm;

    cout << "Enter a day and time: ";
    getline(cin, inputTime);

    int i = 0;

    while (charholder != ' ') {

        charholder = inputTime[i];
        i++;
    }

    day = inputTime.substr(0,i);
    hour = inputTime.substr(i,1);
    minute = inputTime.substr(i+2,2);
    amPm = inputTime.substr(i+5,2);

    }
```

Comment: Why do you have so many strings..

Comment: Your code is completely broken, too many issues

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a single `char` to an `std::string` is OK. But you have many default constructed strings, which you then try to assign elements to using `operator[]` and an index. But they are all size 0, so these locations are not valid.

```
std::string foo; // empty string
foo[0] = 'x':    // Oops! foo[0] holds for the null-termination character. Modifying is UB
foo[1] = 'x':    // Oops! foo[1] is out of bounds
```

Comment: Would it make a difference if I allocated the memory when I declare the variables i.e, "string day[10];"?

Comment: @user1681673 that would be an array of strings. Maybe you want a string of a certain size? For example, `std::string foo(5, 'x')` makes a size 5 string where every character is an `x`.

Comment: Ah, got it. I'm very new to C++, more use to C. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a string with length 0.

```
string hour;
```

And this *does not change the length of the string*.

```
hour[0] = inputTime[i+1];
```

If you need the string to be a particular length, call [`std::string::resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize)